# Array Loop with Mysql Insert

Tags: php

**I have an array called $columns :**

```
 array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Food"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Calories"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "Carbs"
    }
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "Food"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Calories"
    }
```

**Another called values**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "'Fish'"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "'100'"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "'0'"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "'Tatoe'"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "'100'"
}
```

I have columns in my database that represent all possible columns that an array has.The arrays could have 5,6 more or less columns depending on the item.

I have this code that is suppose to generate the sql statement in this sense :

*INSERT INTO MEALS (the columns in that array) VALUES (the values in the value array)*

Here is the code :

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($column); $i++)
        {
        echo("INSERT INTO 'MEALS` ($column[$i]) VALUES ($values[$i])\n");         
        }
```

The problem is for each "MEAL":

n(per column) number of sql queries will be generated.

as such :

```
INSERT INTO `MEALS` (Food) VALUES ('Fish')
INSERT INTO `MEALS` (Calory) VALUES ('100')
INSERT INTO `MEALS` (Carbs) VALUES ('0')
```

Instead of it all being on the same query.

INSERT INTO `MEALS` (Food,Calory,Carbs) VALUES ('Fish','100','0')

So if i insert in the database, 3 rows will be created.

I know i am missing the logic, any help is appreciated

Comment: Why you don't concate the Inserts to one? `INSERT INTO MEALS (Your,Column,Names) VALUES(Your,Values,here),(Another,Value,there);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you genererating the two parts of your query (1 variable for columns in insert and 1 variable for values) inside your array loop?

Once your loop is done, simply concatenate your strings :

$query = "INSERT INTO 'MEALS' (" . $var_column_list . ") VALUES (" . $var_values_list . ")";

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "insert into table(".join($colomn,','). ") values (\"".join($values,'","')."\")";
```

Try using variant of above according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
$colums  = implode(',', $array_of_colums);
$values = implode(',', $array_of_values);
$query = "INSERT INTO `tableName` (".$colums.") VALUES(".$values.") ";
```